# Is there a way to sum up all numbers from an array in one method with a different method?

Tags: java, arrays, math, multidimensional-array, methods

I have a brief idea as to how to add all the numbers in that array in the same method but I am not sure how to use a separate method to add all the numbers. The print2DArray() prints the array with the random numbers out in a 4x4 format. I can't figure out a way to make the method findSum() add up all the numbers in the method print2DArray().

```
public class randomBoard2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findSum(); //I was experimenting with this to see what worked
}
```

//method that prints out the array with random numbers are below

```
public static void print2DArray(){
    
    int[][] a = new int [4][4];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)    
    a[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
     }
    
    for(int[] nums: a) {
        for(int b: nums) {
        System.out.print(b + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

//method that adds up all the numbers in the array above is below

```
public static void findSum() {
    int sum = 0;
```

//The "a" in the for-each loop below is wrong. I'm not sure what to put in there instead.

```
    for(int[] number: a) {
        for(int d: number)
        sum += d;
        System.out.println("The sum of all the numbers is: " + sum);
    }
  }
}
```

I am relatively new to Java so I'm not sure how exactly I should make a method that adds all the numbers in another method. (I apologize in advance for the poor question phrasing).

Comment: `print2DArray` should not be creating and filling the array. It should be passed to `print2DArray`. And the same array should be passed to `findSum`. Simple parameters should do.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the sum of 2D array (named 'a') and print it, try the following code:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int[] array : a) {
    sum += IntStream.of(array).sum();
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 * @author shikai.liu
 * @version 1.0
 * @since JDK1.7
 */
public class TestList {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        print2DArray();
    }

    public static void print2DArray() {
        int sum = 0;
        int[][] a = new int[4][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
                a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }

        for (int[] nums : a) {
            for (int b : nums) {
                sum += b;
                System.out.print(b + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```